# Crear archivo CSV separado por comas con PHP

Tags: php

Estoy generando un archivo csv desde MySQL con PHP/PDO. Le coloco la cabecera, genero el listado pero los graba de manera contínua.

```
<?php
require ('includes/config.php');
$BD = new ConnDB();

$archivo_csv = "saldos.csv";
if(!file_exists($archivo_csv)){
    file_put_contents($archivo_csv,"Código,Nombre,Importe");
}

$sql = "SELECT cod, nom, saldo from cuentas where flag = 'X'";
$sth = $BD->query($sql);
$sth->execute();

if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) { 
    while ($fila = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
        file_put_contents($archivo_csv,"n".join(",",$fila),FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }
?>
```

Esta es la salida:

> Código,Nombre,Importen8,ALYDAR,135.00n21,AGUA SANTA,1442.00n30

Cuál es el error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Necesitas agregar los saltos de línea `\n`. Y para evitar problemas de plataforma, puedes usar en lugar de `\n` a nuestro amigo [`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.constants.php).

Aunque, yo usaría código más optimizado para manejar el archivo y para crear el csv.

- Con [`fputs`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fputs.php)  puedes escribir en el archivo.
- Con el uso de [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php) podemos crear el archivo si no existe y al mismo tiempo verificar si está disponible o no, ya que devuelve `false` si no existe o no se puede crear.

  ```
  <?php
  require ('includes/config.php');
  $BD = new ConnDB(); 

  $archivo_csv = fopen('saldos.csv', 'w');

  if($archivo_csv)
  {
      fputs($archivo_csv, "Código, Nombre, Importe".PHP_EOL));  

      $sql = "SELECT cod, nom, saldo from cuentas where flag = 'X'";
      $sth = $BD->query($sql);
      $sth->execute();

      if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) 
      { 
          while ($fila = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
          {
             fputs($archivo_csv, implode($fila, ',').PHP_EOL);
          }
      }

      fclose($archivo_csv);
  }else{

      echo "El archivo no existe o no se pudo crear";

  }

  ?>
  ```

Aquí una prueba de un resultado :

```
Código,Nombre,Importe
1,Juan Crisóstomo,1
2,Agustín,1
3,Teofilacto,0
4,Alcuino,0
5,Ireneo,1
6,Cirilo,1
7,Hilario,1
```

Comment: Acabo de probar el código. Y muestra el archivo csv más ordenado. Y con las tildes y las eñes, pero al abrirlo en excel las eñes y las tildes se convierten en código basura.

Comment: @Piropeator mmm no sé, si se muestran las tildes y demás me parece que lo está creando en utf-8. No obstante puedes probar a aplicar esto a lo que se escribe en el fichero:  `$datos = mb_convert_encoding(implode($fila, ',')), 'UTF-8', 'OLD-ENCODING');  fputs($archivo_csv, $datos.PHP_EOL);` Yo siempre tengo problemas al abrir los CSV (Excel Mac OsX), pero si los abro en Google Sheets, ningún problema. O sea, puede ser cuestión del Excel de tu equipo, si puedes prueba con Sheets. ¿Cuando lo creas con `fputcsv` no te da problemas de codificación?

Comment: El resultado es igual con `fputcsv`. El `mb-convert_encoding` muestra error **Illegal character encoding specified**. Se parece a `iconv`?

Comment: @Piropeator sí se parece. Pero no creo que sea un problema de codificación. Si tienes Google Drive sube el csv allí y ábrelo con Google Sheets a ver qué ocurre. Creo que es un problema de Excel, no del archivo.

Comment: Una solución momentánea es abrir el CSV con Notepad y darle Grabar Como (Encoding UTP-8) sobre el mismo archivo. Luego abrirlo con Excel (que usan los usuarios) y ya aparecen los códigos y las tíldes. Igual revisaré el encoding. Creo que leí que Excel lee ISO pero no encuentro el texto. Gracias igual.

Comment: Una consulta. He realizado cambios y he integrado los módulos. Debo crear otra pregunta o edito la original?

Comment: @Piropeator dado que SO funciona por preguntas y la pregunta original planteaba la posibilidad de leer un archivo CSV, a la cual responden las dos respuestas existentes hasta ahora... considero que el problema de la codificación debería ser planteado en una nueva pregunta. De ese modo esta pregunta serviría como punto de referencia para el problema original y podrás tener más atención al nuevo problema si lo planteas en una nueva pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

Usa [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fputcsv.php)  es una función php creada para escribir en formato csv ademas ya recibe un arreglo por lo que no tendrás problema al ingresar los parámetros.

```
require ('includes/config.php');
$BD = new ConnDB();

$i = 0;
do {

  $archivo_csv = "saldos_$i.csv"
  $i++;
} while(file_exists($archivo_csv));

$csv = fopen($archivo_csv, 'x+');
fputcsv($csv,array ('Código','Nombre','Importe'));


$sql = "SELECT cod, nom, saldo from cuentas where flag = 'X'";
$sth = $BD->query($sql);


if ($sth->execute() !==  false  && $sth->rowCount() > 0) { 


  while ($fila = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    fputcsv($csv, $fila);
  }


}

fclose($csv);
```

Comment: Puedes explicarme para qué usas la parte del do{}??

Comment: Eso es no es necesario como vi en el código original **file_exists($archivo_csv)**  me di cuenta que si el archivo existía el contenido se pondría al final y par evitarlo y no sobre escribir el archivo. ese parte del código se asegura que no exista un el archivo que se va a escribir buscando un nombre que no exista para crear el archivo. si existe saldos_0.csv trata con saldos_1.csv,.. etc.

Comment: Al generar el archivo csv muestra las tildes y las eñes correctamente, pero al abrir el archivo csv con excel muestra código basura en lugar de tiles y eñes. Cómo puedo solucionar eso?

Comment: Esto es por que excel usa la codificación de window y tu seguramente estas creando el archivo con UTF8() usa ISO, la configuración por defecto de windows, o cambia las propiedades de la aplicación excel

Comment: @Piropeator Mi [respuesta primera](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/111764/revisions) se basaba en `fputcsv` pero al hacer la prueba del código me di cuenta de que esta función tiene un parámetro llamado *enclosure*  el cual, cuando un valor del archivo tiene más de una palabra, **lo rodea de comillas**. Esta línea, por ejemplo: `1,Juan Crisóstomo,1` la creaba así: **`1,"Juan Crisóstomo",1`**, dado que no era un resultado deseable, cambié mi respuesta a la actual.

Comment: El que tenga el texto entre comillas hace que el formato csv sea correcto ya que de lo contrario si un campo tiene una coma lo toma como 2 campos

Answer (score -3):

Si lo que necesitas es un archivo generado que distribuya cada dato en una celda independiente, usa la librería PHPExcel. Solo tienes que incluirla en tu script, y consultar alguno de los ejemplos de archivos generados que contiene. Te digo, acabarás eso en un parpadeo.

Saludos!

Comment: Hola Nicole, muchas gracias por responder, en lo posible te recomendaria si pudieses agregar un pequeño ejemplo de lo que respondes al usuario, asi seria mas facil para que el entendiera la solucion al problema y asi ayudarias a futuros usuarios. Saludos!

Comment: las respuestas deben ser claras y objetivas además de evitar el uso de lenguaje inapropiado que no contribuye a la solución del problema en lo absoluto