# Guardar excel en el servidor

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Hola estoy generando un excel a partir de una consulta en mysql y creo una tabla a partir de esos datos y genero el excel con los header lo que quiero es que no me lo descargue localmente si no guardarlo en el servidor, depronto alguien sabe como hacerlo?

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $nombre . ".xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
```

Comment: Si tienes la url que genera el excel funcionando, te sugiero ocupar la función `file_put_contents` Alguien en el [foro en inglés de la misma comunidad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21216351/save-excel-file-to-server-using-php) preguntó algo similar que tú ocupando esta función para guardar un archivo excel con PHP en el servidor, échale un vistazo, seguramente te servirá. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Crear archivo CSV separado por comas con PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111752/crear-archivo-csv-separado-por-comas-con-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione asi por si a alguien le puede servir

```
 file_put_contents("/home/http/miclubappdev/httpdocs/plataform/cron/example.xls", $html);
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe brevemente el funcionamiento del código. Lee [answer]. _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._